# How can I get the 'Last' value from this dictionary?

Tags: python, json, dictionary

I'm working with an API that is sending my Python program the following data back:

```
{"success":"true","message":"","result":   
 [{"Last":"0.00000000","Bid":"42258.06451613","Ask":"100000000.0"}]}
```

I'm pretty new to working with JSON in Python but thought I could do something like:

```
data = json.load(urllib2.urlopen("apicall"))
last = data["success"]["message"]["result"]["Last"]
```

but apparently I need to use integers instead. So when I do

```
last = data[0][0][0][0]
```

I'm told that's an invalid key. So my question is: what is the proper way to get the value of the 'Last' key in this example?

Comment: `data["result"][0]["Last"]`. Indenting your JSON in order to read it will help; so will accessing one key at a time to find out where the problems are.

Answer (score 3):

The proper way is to address the outer dictionary, then index the list, then get the `'Last'` key:

```
last = data['result'][0]['Last']
```

Demo:

```
>>> from pprint import pprint
>>> data = {"success":"true","message":"","result":   
...  [{"Last":"0.00000000","Bid":"42258.06451613","Ask":"100000000.0"}]}
>>> pprint(data)
{'message': '',
 'result': [{'Ask': '100000000.0',
             'Bid': '42258.06451613',
             'Last': '0.00000000'}],
 'success': 'true'}
>>> data['result']
[{'Ask': '100000000.0', 'Bid': '42258.06451613', 'Last': '0.00000000'}]
>>> data['result'][0]
{'Ask': '100000000.0', 'Bid': '42258.06451613', 'Last': '0.00000000'}
>>> data['result'][0]['Last']
'0.00000000'
```

Your first attempt tried to address all the keys in the top-level dictionary, which would have failed because `data['success']` is a string, and strings cannot be indexed by `['message']`.

Your second attempt failed because the top-level object is a dictionary, not a sequence, and there is no `0` key in it.